# creating css keyframes in loop

Tags: css, less

I am trying to create a bunch of animations that should be calculated.
I am omitting the actual calculation of those animations here as they are not relevant.
The problem I am having is in producing the correct `@keyframes` constructs.

here is my stripped back less:

```
.Entry(@animCount, @frameResolution)
{
    .CreateAnim(@animNum) when (@animNum =< @animCount)
    {
        @keyframesname: ~'MyAnimation-@{animNum}';
        .frame(@frame) when (@frame =< 100%)
        {
            @{frame}
            {
                hello1: @frame;
                hello2: @animNum;
            }
            // .frame( ((@frame + @frameResolution)) );
        }

        @keyframes @keyframesname {
            .frame(0%);
        }
        .CreateAnim(((@animNum + 1 )));
    }
    .CreateAnim(1);
}
```

and this is how it might be called:

```
.Entry(3, 50%);
```

I'm compiling it like so:
`lessc -m=strict-legacy bug.less bug.css`

I expected output such as this:

```
@keyframes MyAnimation-1 {
  0% {
    hello1: 0%;
    hello2: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes MyAnimation-2 {
  0% {
    hello1: 0%;
    hello2: 2;
  }
}
@keyframes MyAnimation-3 {
  0% {
    hello1: 0%;
    hello2: 3;
  }
}
```

But in fact MyAnimation-1 also contains all the keyframes from MyAnimation-2 and MyAnimation-3, while MyAnimation-2 contains also contains all the keyframes from MyAnimation-3

Is this a bug in less, or have I done something wrong?

```
$lessc --version
lessc 3.9.0 (Less Compiler) [JavaScript]
```

Comment: W/o getting too much into details - I'd suggest to move the inner loop  mixin (`.frame`) definition out of the outer one (`.CreateAnim`). The problem is that each next outer mixin call *defines new* `.frame` mixin which cascades to its previous definitions (and all end up in the same scope). Somewhere at Less gihub repo there's one or two issues where this is described in details.

Comment: That's a good point, probably something I should do anyway from an efficency perspective, even if it doesn't fix the problem. The Snag is I think the actual code might require the nesting. But maybe there is a way around that.

Comment: *the actual code might require the nesting* - not really, just make the `@animNum` to be an additional parameter of `.frame` and it can be defined *anywhere*. Alternatively - since the issue apples only to  called in the global scope (if I recall correctly), if you put some ruleset (could be just `& {}`) around an initial call or one of definitions definitions - the loop will behave as you expect the way it is.

Comment: Also note that Less v3 provides `each` function to create loops w/o recursive mixins.

Comment: I ran into more problems after trying your suggestions and resorted to generating a more static-ish less file from javascript instead.